# Finding summations with variable lower bounds

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{j=i}^n -i$$.

Is this solved by splitting it into,
$$\sum_{j=i}^n -1 * \sum_{j=i}^n i$$
and then,

$(i-n-1)$ * $i$

to get the answer?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{j=i}^n f(j)\cdot g(j)\neq \left(\sum\limits_{j=i}^n f(j)\right)\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{j=i}^ng(j)\right)$.   For counterexample $1+1+1=1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1\neq (1+1+1)\cdot (1+1+1)$

Comment: You *can* however *factor out* the $-1$ in which case you recognize that $\sum\limits_{j=i}^n -i =(-1)\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{j=i}^n i\right)$.  You can also further factor out the $i$ in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\sum_{j=i}^{n} a  = a\sum_{j=i}^{n} 1 = a(n-i+1).$$ In your case, $a = -i$.